# OAuth/OAuth2 RFC question

Tags: standards, oauth, authorization, oauth2

This question is about a line from the OAuth2 rfc - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

In Section 2.3, there is this line

```
The client MUST NOT use more than one authentication method in each request.
```

What exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

It's an error for the user to attempt to authenticate twice, e.g. via HTTP Basic Auth and then via Post.  I believe that this is to avoid specifying what should be done if the user sends two different client_ids via two different authentication methods - rather than specifying which authentication takes precedence, it's simpler to forbid this scenario altogether

Comment: What if the client_ids are same via the 2 authentication methods? i.e. there is 2 Factor authentication - i.e password and then an OTP?

Comment: @user93353 The server for which OAuth is a delegate may employ 2 factor authentication when issuing the token, but that's outside of OAuth's purview